# Why does reversing a list using slice notation with 0 as "stop" not return the entire list?

Tags: python, list, slice

In the following example:

```
foo = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 1, 2, 3]
```

`foo[0:6:1]` will print all elements in `foo`. However, `foo[6:0:i-1]` will omit the 1st or 0th element.

```
>>> foo[6:0:-1]
[3, 2, 1, 'blue', 'white']
```

I understand that I can use `foo.reverse()` or `foo[::-1]` to print the list in reverse, but why doesn't `foo[6:0:-1]` print the entire list?

Comment: Note also the `foo[7:None:-1]` possibility :)

Comment: I never used python before just trying to understand slice notation, my question is why foo[6:0:-1] is not throwing out of index error, does python not care about it? because 6 index is not available in above example array.

Comment: @MubasharAhmad Slicing is not indexing and does not throw out any error when going beyond the bounds. Indexing does throw exception when out of bounds, though.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Slice notation in short:

```
[ <first element to include> : <first element to exclude> : <step> ]
```

If you want to include the first element when reversing a list, leave the middle element empty, like this:

```
foo[::-1]
```

You can also find some good information about Python slices in general here:
[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Comment: This: `[ <first element to include> : <first element to exclude> : <step> ]` is the clearest explanation of the slice syntax I've seen. Calling it "first element to exclude" really makes it obvious what's going on.

Comment: What about negative slicing with negative steps? I still don't get it.

Comment: When you use a negative index as either `<first element to include>` or `<first element to exclude>` it is indexing from the back of the list, so `-1` is the last element, `-2` is the second to last element, etc.  So for example, `x[-1:-4:-1]` would get the last three elements of `x` in reversed order.  So you might interpret this as "moving backwards take each element (`-1` step) from the last element in the list (`-1 <first element to include>`) up until but not including the fourth element from the end (`-4 <first element to include>`)".

Comment: When reversing (i.e. if `<step>` is `-1`), it helps me to think `<first element to include, moving from right to left>`. So, to get the `n` "leftmost" elements from a list in reverse order: `foo[n-1::-1]`. To get the `n` "rightmost" elements in reverse order: `foo[-1:-n-1:-1]`.

Comment: How do you make the first element to exclude "the element before `foo[0]`"?

Comment: The notation is very useful. The key if it's `-1` is to remember it will get elements from back to front`<--` when outputting, so you `start` index must be greater than the `end` index (even if those indexes are negative numbers)

Answer (score 14):

If you are having trouble remembering slice notation, you could try doing the [Hokey Cokey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokey_cokey):

[**In**: **Out**: **Shake it all about**]

[First element to **in**clude: First element to leave **out**: The **step** to use]

YMMV

Answer (score 10):

This answer might be a little outdated, but it could be helpful for someone who stuck with same problem.
You can get reverse list with an arbitrary end - up to 0 index, applying second in-place slice like this:

```
>>> L = list(range(10))
>>> L
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> (start_ex, end) = (7, 0)
>>> L[end:start_ex][::-1]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: This is actually pretty useful, because you can use the same syntax for all cases. You don’t have to treat 0 as a special case.

Comment: This makes more sense than Python/numpy's default behavior for negative slicing, because normally ones wants to slice and/or reverse an image or tensor aligned to a given edge, whereas Python/numpy lose that last row/column of the data o_O.

Answer (score 8):

This is a very good question, and, in my opinion, none of the above answers really answer the question being asked. Partly because an intellectually honest answer may reveal a weakness of Python type system. And the same weakness exists in some other languages.

A more intellectually honest answer would probably be:
*Python slicing does not generalize well.*

Precisely, one can traverse a collection in one direction with `collection[begin:end]` but `collection[end:begin:-1]` does not work. It does not work because the first index is `0` but the "index before the first index" is not `-1`. Thus, `collection[end:-1:-1]` does not evaluate to what we would legitimately expect.

The `[first to include : first to exclude : step]` explanation is flawed. If "first to exclude" is the one before the first element, you cannot express it the same way you would in the case that you wanted to include that same first element.

In conclusion, you're not crazy to expect generality, it is just not there.

Answer (score 7):

> ...why foo[6:0:-1] doesn't print the entire list?

Because the middle value is the *exclusive*, rather than inclusive, stop value.  The [interval notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Excluding_the_endpoints) is [start, stop).

This is exactly how [x]range works:

```
>>> range(6, 0, -1)
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Those are the indices that get included in your resulting list, and they don't include 0 for the first item.

```
>>> range(6, -1, -1)
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Another way to look at it is:

```
>>> L = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 1, 2, 3]
>>> L[0:6:1]
['red', 'white', 'blue', 1, 2, 3]
>>> len(L)
6
>>> L[5]
3
>>> L[6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The index 6 is beyond (one-past, precisely) the valid indices for L, so excluding it from the range as the excluded stop value:

```
>>> range(0, 6, 1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Still gives you indices for each item in the list.

Comment: `range` can do it but slice can't do it, because `-1` is the last element. So `l=[1, 2, 3]`, `l[2:-1:-1] == []`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to work if you use a negative stop value. Try this:

```
foo[-1:-7:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
>>>foo[::-1]
```

This displays the reverse of the list from the end element to the start,

Answer (score 0):

Complement. to reverse step by 2:

```
A = [1,2,2,3,3]
n = len(A)
res = [None] * n
mid = n//2 + 1 if n%2 == 1 else n//2

res[0::2] = A[0:mid][::-1]
res[1::2] = A[0:mid][::-1]
print(res)
```

[2, 3, 2, 3, 1]

Answer (score 0):

formalizing the answer from [andrew-clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505154/andrew-clark) a little bit more:

Suppose the list `v` and  `v[n1:n2:n3]` slice. 
`n1` is initial position, `n2` is final position and `n3` is step

Let's write some pseucode in a Python way:

```
n3 = 1  if (n3 is missing) else n3
if n3==0:
   raise exception # error, undefined step
```

**First part: n3 positive**

```
if n3>0:
   slice direction is from left to right, the most common direction         

   n1 is left slice position in `v` 
   if n1 is missing: 
      n1 = 0   # initial position
   if n1>=0:
      n1 is a normal position
   else: 
     (-n1-1) is the position in the list from right to left 

   n2 is right slice position in `v` 
   if n2 is missing: 
      n2 = len(x)  # after final position
   if n2>=0:
      n2 is a normal final position (exclusive)
   else: 
      -n2-1 é the final position in the list from right to left 
       (exclusive)
```

**Second part: n3 negative**

```
else: 
  slice direction is from right to left (inverse direction)

  n1 is right slice position in `v` 
  if n1 is missing: 
     n1 = -1   # final position is last position in the list.
  if n1>=0:
     n1 is a normal position
  else: 
     (-n1-1) is the position in the list from right to left 

  n2 is  left slice position in `v` 
  if n2 is missing: 
     n2 = -len(x)-1   # before 1st character  (exclusive)
  if n2>=0:
     n2 is a normal final position (exclusive)
  else: 
     -n2-1 is the ending position in the list from right to left 
     (exclusive)
```

Now the original problema: How to reverse a list with slice notation?

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(L(::-1)) # [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Why?
`n1 is missing and n3<0` **=>** `n1=0`
`n2 is missing and n3<0` **=>** `n2 = -len(x)-1`

So `L(::-1) == L(-1:-11:-1)`

Comment: So far clearest explanation in the whole web I've seen. However I think it could be slightly improved. "(-n1-1) is the position in the list from right to left" is correct but I bet most people think this in term of "normal" array indexes from 0..size-1 so (-n1-1)  would become ((size-1)-(-n1-1))) i.e.( size+n1)