# Converting a number string into MD5 with python

Tags: python, md5, geohashing

Inspired by the XKCD geohashing comic (http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/geohashing.png), I thought I'd have a go at coding a generator in Python. I've hit a block with the major part of it, though: The converting to MD5 and then to decimal.

Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit:** After looking at the comic here is a more complete solution for [XKCD geohashing](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/geohashing.png):

```
>>> md5 = hashlib.md5('2005-05-26-10458.68').hexdigest()     # get MD5 as hex string
>>> float.fromhex('0.' + md5[:16])                           # first half as float
0.85771326770700229
>>> float.fromhex('0.' + md5[16:])                           # second half as float
0.54454306955928211
```

Here is a more general answer for "converting to MD5 and then to decimal":

Say you want the decimal MD5 of the string `'hello world'`, you could use the following:

```
>>> int(hashlib.md5('hello world').hexdigest(), 16)
125893641179230474042701625388361764291L
```

The [`hash.hexdigest()`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) function returns a hexadecimal string, and `int(hex_str, 16)` is how you can [convert a hexadecimal string to a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209550/505154).

Comment: Oh blimey. This got a lot more complicated than I thought it may have been... Ah well. Must forge on. If I might ask, how do [:16] and [16:] grab the two separate part of the MD5 string?

Comment: @dantdj, this is called slicing, you can find some good information about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5877008/505154).  It is basically `[start:stop:step]` where the final colon and the step are optional.  `[:16]` would mean take the first 16 characters, and `[16:]` means take everything from the 17th character (because of zero-based indexing) to the end.

Comment: Ah, of course! I was wondering why 16 was chosen. Everything starts looking a bit obvious when it's laid out in front of you like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `int('db931', 16)` to convert the hexadecimal (base-16) string `db931` to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clue - this encodes [the example image](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/geohashing.png) and produces the numbers you will find there.

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> hash = md5("2005-05-26-10458.68").hexdigest()
>>> hash
'db9318c2259923d08b672cb305440f97'
>>> int(hash[:16],16)/16.**16
0.8577132677070023
>>> int(hash[16:],16)/16.**16
0.5445430695592821
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to chop and change a bit but I've got a basic version working now. Just have to remove the superfluous decimal points.