# UnboundLocalError at inversing a string

Tags: python, string, split

```
def FirstReverse(str):


    chaine = str.split(' ');

     for i in range(len(chaine), -1):
       inverse = chaine[i]
   return inverse ;    

print FirstReverse(raw_input())
```

i want to inverse a string but i have some difficulties , i got this error message

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'inverser' referenced before assignment

Comment: Python doesn't need `;`s on the end of a statement.

Comment: You override the value of `inverse` in each iteration of the loop. You probably want to change that.

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code, it is not clear what do you want to return here.

Comment: The code looks like you want to reverse the order of the words in a string and not the string itself. You could do that with `' '.join(reversed(sentence.split()))`.

Comment: As a general rule, `for i in range(len(x)...):` solutions are usually, though not invariably, unpythonic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a negative step argument to range to get a reversed range list.

```
range(len(chaine)-1, -1, -1)   #start from len(chaine)-1
```

As because `range(len(chaine), -1)` returns `[]`, the loop never executes and `inverse` never gets defined.

Easiest way to inverse a string is to use the extended slice notation `[::-1]`.

Comment: i fellowed your advice and changed it , but i got just the first word of the sentence.  <br/> def FirstReverse(str):
    
    chaine = str.split(' ');
    for i in range(len(chaine)-1, -1, -1):
        inverse = chaine[i]
        print i
        
    return (inverse)
          
        
print FirstReverse(raw_input())

Answer (score 1):

Your for statement is always false and inverse gets initialized only if for loop condition is met, so the code doesn't reach the point where inverse gets a value (and by that, gets defined/bound). You should introduce the variable in a place that always gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to reverse a list is [to use slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) with [a step of `-1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5876998/78845):

```
def FirstReverse(s):
    words = s.split(' ')
    return words[::-1]
```

#### Notes:

1. [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) is a Python built-in, avoid re-using it
2. You don't need to finish statements with semicolons;