# Python list slice

Tags: python, list

Why the first output is including the first element (is seems to me like good behavior, because it starts with `0` index (that is that first element) and then increment with `len(a)-1` (last element)).

Problem is that the second example (if it always starts with zero index and then increment) should be something like `[1, 5, 4, 3, 2]`, or?

**Output 1:** `[1, 5]`

**Output 2:** `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(a[::len(a)-1])

print(a[::-1])
```

Comment: Found this SO ref : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876998/reversing-list-using-slice-notation` . It will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last parameter in a slice is the step value. It starts from 0, if the step is positive, -1 if the step is negative. [Relevant piece of code from `sliceobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Objects/sliceobject.c#l152),

```
defstart = *step < 0 ? length-1 : 0;
```

So, when you say

```
a[::-1]
```

and as the step is negative, it just starts from the last element. It keeps on incrementing the index by -1 and the generated list is returned. So, it basically reverses the list.

But, when you say

```
a[::len(a)-1]
```

the step value is 4. Since the step is positive, it starts from the first element, which is `1` and increments the index by 4 and picks the element at index 4 (initial index (0) + 4 = 4), which is 5. That is why `[1, 5]` is returned.

Comment: Note that it changes the *default* start and stop rather than switching their interpretation - otherwise, `a[0:-1:-1]` would be equivalent to `a[::-1]` instead of being empty.

Answer (score 2):

what you have is called [extended slices](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)
whatever you mention after `::` is the step value you wan to add to the `0` index element

so

```
>>> print(a[::len(a)-1])
[1, 5]
```

is basically

```
 >>> print(a[::4)
    [1, 5]
```

get the `0` th element and add 4 to the index and get me the next element.

Similar behaviour for negative numbers.

```
>>> print(a[::-1)
        [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

add `-1` to the index ( or subtract 1 from the index ) which makes it `0-1` or `5`(the last element in the array).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how python list slicing works:

```
a[start:end] # items start through end-1
```

There is also the step value, which can be used with any of the above:

```
a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step
```

The other feature is that start or end may be a negative number, which means it counts from the end of the array instead of the beginning. So:

```
a[-1]    # last item in the array
a[-2:]   # last two items in the array
a[:-2]   # everything except the last two items
```

So, in your case,

`a[::len(a)-1]` 
slices the array from start to end with step of `len(a)-1 = 4` i.e. [1, 5] (skips the three items and retains the fourth one)

`a[::-1]` inverts the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a negative `step`, the defaults for start and stop are (roughly) switched: it will *start* at the end of the list, and *stop* at the beginning. I say 'roughly' because, as you've seen, it is adjusted so that `a[::-1]` still includes all of the elements of `a` - meaning, it is actually equivalent to `a[-1:-len(a):-1]`. The reason for this is likely related to how awkward that syntax is, compared to how useful reversing a sequence is compared to it meaning `a[0:-1:-1]`, which is empty.

This is true of all builtins that support this syntax (lists, tuples and strings), but not *necessarily* true of any types from 3rd party modules that support it (it is up to the individual classes what slicing means for them).