# Why list reverse returns Null?

Tags: python

I have example list like this:

```
l = [1,2,3]

print(l.reverse())
#give None instead [3, 2, 1]
```

How is that? How can I reverse list?

Comment: tried it in IDLE,Python 3.3. Worked well!

Comment: list.reverse()
Reverse the elements of the list, in place.

Comment: Try ``l[::-1]`` to make a reversed copy of the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I reverse list?

The list *is* being reversed. But `list.reverse` reverses in place, and does not return anything to the caller. You can verify this by printing the list *after* calling `reverse` on it:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> print(l)
>>> [3, 2, 1]
```

If in doubt, use the help:

```
>>> help(list.reverse)

Help on method_descriptor:
reverse(...)
    L.reverse() -- reverse *IN PLACE*
```

(Python 2.7 documentation)

Answer (score 4):

From docs:

> `list.`**`reverse`()**
>
> Reverse the elements of the list, in place.
>
> You might have noticed that methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort` that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default `None`. This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Python isn't a functional programming language—it's imperative. When you call the `list.reverse()` method you're *mutating the original list*:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l.reverse()
print l
# prints [3, 2, 1]
```

A method that returns `None` is similar to a `void` function/method in the C/C++/Java world. Since `list.reverse()` mutates the original list, it doesn't have anything meaningful to return, so the return value is `None`.

As @YS-L pointed out in his comment, [you can use Python's list slicing notation to create a reversed copy of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877008/1427124):

```
l = [1,2,3]
print l[::-1]
# prints [3, 2, 1]
```