# Why does my_list[2, -1, -1] return an empty list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

I looked for answers but couldn't find anything.

```
>my_list = [7,8,9]
>my_list[2:1:-1]
[9]
>my_list[2:0:-1]
[9, 8]
>my_list[2:-1:-1]
[] # I would expect [9, 8, 7]
```

I am aware there are other ways to reverse a list, but I'm curious why the above doesn't work? `my_list[2,None,-1]` does work.

Comment: I don't think `my_list[2,1,-1]` is a valid syntax for indexing, did you mean `my_list[2:1:-1]` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversing a list using slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876998/reversing-a-list-using-slice-notation)

Comment: @DavidYappeter thanks fixed the notation. Unfortunately not, I am specifically wondering why the `-1` exclusive boundary doesn't work

Comment: according to the question above second element mean `first element to exclude`, which mean you if you place it with `0`, it will ignore first element, and if you place `-1` which mean the 'last element' and that is index `2`(your start of iteration) in your case, it will be an empty array, `None` will works

Comment: @DavidYappeter Yeah kind of confusing. I would think "first element to exclude" being the last element would mean include the first element. I would read it as include elements `2, 1, 0` and do not include -1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate from the back until the first element, leave the second element empty:
`my_list[2::-1]` well or write it sorter `my_list[::-1]`

Comment: Yeah this was my workaround.

`res += matrix[bottom][::-1][left+1:right+1]`
vs 
`res += matrix[bottom][right -1, left-1, -1]`

Comment: Unfortunately that adds another operation tho just to get around the syntax